# Parse.com - fetch() not refreshing ParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to refresh a Parse object to make sure I have the most up to date values before performing some calculations and saving. I have used the `fetch()` method for this task. However after I edited an entry using the Data Browser, `fetch()` did not return the updated object. The object fetched was from the local data storage, even though I did not use `fetchFromLocalDatastore()`. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue simply by updating my Parse sdk to the latest release. It's a bug that was fixed in v1.9.2